# Charcter '+' is getting replace by space in request parameter

Tags: javascript, jsp, security, jakarta-ee, servlets

```
// jsp abc.jsp
Code:
<%
String a = (String)session.getAttribute("CSRF_NONCE");
String b = a.replace("+","%2B")
%>
<a href="javascript:newWin=void(window.open('<%=Url%>netmarkets/jsp/meeting/xyz.jsp?&u8=1&height=450,&CSRF_NONCE=<%=a%>','','toolbar=no'))">Action Items </a>
```

Requirement: I want to pass one request parameter in above link after reading that from session(attr-"CSRF_NONCE").

Problem: When I read "CSRF_NONCE" parameter in **xyz.jsp**, I find that character '+' is replaced by space in parameter CSRF_NONCE.

I tried string **b**  in link but I got the same problem. Actually from xyz.jsp, An api is called which checks that CSRF_NONCE is present in both session and request.

```
// debug output using System.out.println->SOP
// In xyz.jsp
SOP(request.getSession().getAttribute("CSRF_NONCE"))-> tqEtncjrVemCzNXjsFLu4sYDSuvZFw6g6j4meBSbXXQ=:1404880919271:6HVrHD/ZKeOME+1k76KOUA==
SOP(request.getParameter("CSRF_NONCE"))             -> tqEtncjrVemCzNXjsFLu4sYDSuvZFw6g6j4meBSbXXQ=:1404880919271:6HVrHD/ZKeOME 1k76KOUA==
```

Comment: Is the URL on the same server ? Is the same session still valid on the new URL ? If so, you can access that attribute from session only.

Comment: URL is on same server. I am reading it from session only and after that I try to add it as request parameter. This must be available in request for xyz.jsp

Comment: Yes, so why can't you read it from the session itself in the JSP. Also if the issue is with space, you can use the [encodeURIComponent()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) function of javascript for encoding the variable.